# Get php inside of a self-executing js function?

Tags: javascript, php

You have a .js.php file and you want to populate a self-executing function with some dynamic-php-controlled variables.

Can it be done? Should it be avoided?

If you have something like..

```
(function(funkyFresh){
    funkyFresh.someVar = 'this value is important for somebody'; 
})();
```

where 'd' is dependent on some serverside magic so that the client gets js tailored for their instance. So the function above would become..

```
(function(funkyFresh){
    funkyFresh.someVar = <?php echo 'this value works better for you' ?>;
})();
```

I guess you could just have different functions/files for different people, but could this work in any form? I ran a quick test locally and it looks like the `<?php` statement gets picked up as a syntax error inside of the function, so I had to drop it outside of the function and name some globals for function consumption. Any ideas on getting those values into the namespace instead?

Comment: Do it as much as you can. Sometimes you might require quotes before and after the php code.

Comment: Most probably as @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez said, the quotes are problem. When the PHP value returns a string, it will result into `var x = some_string;`, and you need `var x = "some_string";`, so you'd need `var x = "<?php echo 'some_string'; ?>";`

Comment: The most elegant solution would be to asynchronously query the server side magic with an http request and upon recieving a response, to use the value from response.

Comment: I found out that the "Beautifier" I have on my editor throws a space between '<' and '?php' and that's the reason my function broke! With that solved I guess my bigger concern was that writing JS interspersed with PHP snippets was "uncouth"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am personally entirely against generating js with php.  I would much rather do an ajax call and return json.  If I had to avoid ajax, it would be something like this:

PHP:

```
<script>
    window.server_vars = <?php json_encode(["funkyFresh" => ["some_var" => "This value works better for you"]]); ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/javascript.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
(function(funkyFresh){
    funkyFresh.someVar = window.server_vars.funkyFresh.some_var; 
})();
```

Comment: Is that a personal preference or should I be worried about generating code with PHP? I am using the WordPress API with Angular to render configuration options that their current REST API doesn't allow access to.

Comment: There are things to worry about - the browser could cache the JS, and so it might not have the updated variables.  It's harder to know whether you are generating valid javascript.  But primarily, personal preference - in general, code shouldn't generate more code.  BUT, I'm sure there are valid uses.  Regardless, if you are going to be generating JS variables, I would make sure to use `json_encode` to protect yourself from messing things up: `funkyFresh = <?php json_encode(['some_var' => 'whatever']); ?>;` for example